# Add async/await while using mysql package with Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am creating this Migration JS script using Node JS. Below is the full code of this migrate.js file.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
});

// Create Connection
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('MySQL connected as id ' + con.threadId);
});

// Create Database
const db_name = 'nuxt_mysql';
con.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + db_name, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`Database "${db_name}" created.`);

  // Select db
  con.changeUser({database : db_name}, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Database "${db_name}" selected.`);

    // Create Tables
    createTables();
  });
});


// Create Tables
function createTables(){
  createArticlesTable();
  createUsersTable();

  // Close Connection after tables are created
  con.end();
  console.log('MySQL connection closed.');
}

// Create Articles Table
function createArticlesTable(){
  let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (

      id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      body TEXT NOT NULL,
      date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )`;
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Table "articles" created.`);
  });
}

// Create Users Table
function createUsersTable(){
  let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (

      id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      full_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY (email)
  )`;
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Table "users" created.`);
  });
}
```

This script create a database first. Then it selects this db and then creates tables under it using different functions created for every table.

When I run **node migrate.js** , this is the output.

```
MySQL connected as id 257
Database "nuxt_mysql" created.
Database "nuxt_mysql" selected.
MySQL connection closed.
Table "articles" created.
Table "users" created.
```

Now the problem is, I want to close the mysql connection after all the tables have been created. And I think I will have to add async function somewhere. I am not very good with async/await so decided to post it.

Comment: To use async/await you need your callback converting into promises.  You can do this either using the Promise constructor pattern, or use the nodes util promisify.  Or you could even use an npm module were someone has done this for you.. eg.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572105/getting-query-object-instead-of-results-with-async-await-function-and-npm-mysql/62575227#62575227

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async-await` on a function that returns a promise. You can use a promise wrapper or `mysql2` module which uses bluebird promises.

A code snippet from `mysql2`

```
async function main() {
  // get the client
  const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
  // create the connection
  const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});
  // query database
  const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = ? AND `age` > ?', ['Morty', 14]);
}
```

Or you can use [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) which is promise wrapper for MySQL

Alternatively:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const databaseConfig = {
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(databaseConfig)
const promiseQuery = promisify(pool.query).bind(pool)
const promisePoolEnd = promisify(pool.end).bind(pool)

const query = `select 1;`
const result = await promiseQuery(query) // use in async function

promisePoolEnd()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to return new Promise() while creating tables using db.query method and then updated createTables() method to use those promises. Now its working as expected.

Here is the code.

```
// Create Tables
function createTables(){
  Promise.all([
    createArticlesTable(),
    createUsersTable()
  ]).then(() => {
    con.end();
    console.log("MySQL connection closed.");
  });
}

// Create Articles Table
function createArticlesTable(){
  let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (

      id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      body TEXT NOT NULL,
      date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`Table "articles" created.`);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

// Create Users Table
function createUsersTable(){
  let sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (

      id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      full_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      date_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY (email)
  )`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`Table "users" created.`);
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```