# Getting Query object instead of results with Async/await function and npm-mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have this function which is `async` and i'm trying to make a simple query from `npm-mysql` db.

```
let sortCategory = async (id) => {
    try {
      var sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=?';
      var results = await connection.query(sql, id);
      // console.log(results);
      return(results);
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But instead of results inside the `results` variable i just get the query object.

```
Query {                                                                                                                               
  _events:                                                                                                                            
   [Object: null prototype] {                                                                                                         
     error: [Function],                                                                                                               
     packet: [Function],                                                                                                              
     timeout: [Function],                                                                                                             
     end: [Function] },                                                                                                               
  _eventsCount: 4,                                                                                                                    
  _maxListeners: undefined,                                                                                                           
  _callback: undefined,                                                                                                               
  _callSite:                                                                                                                          
   Error                                                                                                                              
       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)                      
       at Connection.query (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)                              
       at sortCategory (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\server\routes\categories.js:35:38)                                            
       at router.post (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\server\routes\categories.js:48:31)                                             
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7),                                                                 
  _ended: false,                                                                                                                      
  _timeout: undefined,                                                                                                                
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },                                                                              
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=\'0\'',                                                                              
  values: '0',                                                                                                                        
  .... }
```

The `query` as seen in object is

```
    sql: 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=\'0\'',                                                                              
    values: '0',
```

**EDIT#1**

an async/await for `INSERT` query does works. it's only when i need to retrieve data back that i don't get it.

but i can't manage to get the results back even though i do have some in table that should return.
i feel like there is something i still not quite understand about mysql and async calls.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = ?', ['David'], function (error, results, fields) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query
  // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)
});
```

You code should became

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=?';

connection.query(sql, [id], function (error, results, fields) {
  if(error){
      return error;  
  }
  return results;
});
```

Comment: Thanks 
an async/await for `INSERT` query does works. it's only when i need to retrieve data back that i don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I use async/await of mysql query like this:

```
var getCategories = function (id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var sql = `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=?`;
        connection.query(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                resolve({
                    status: "error",
                    message: "Error Getting Data",
                    debug: err
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

try {
    var categories = await getCategories();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Above code is very different from yours but you can use the above method to use in further case

Comment: But this is just changing `async/await` to another version of `Promise syntax` (a dirtier one). i could leave my `async` function as is, and just change the connection action to return a callback. But i want to maintain in my code a unified aproach for promises. The `try/catch` is more readable to me. also a `async/awaits` for `INSERT` query works. it's only when i need to recieve data back that i don't get it.

Comment: `connection.query` doesn't have that kind of syntax or function you have used in your code. `var results = await connection.query(sql, id);` <--- this is not a valid MySQL fn

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your helpful posts fedesc. I’d been struggling with this for days. Based on your lead, I ended up with this which is elegant relative to my earlier attempts:

```js
'use strict';
const mysql = require('mysql');
const config = require('./config.js');
const util = require('util'); // needed for async support


const ac = awaitableConnection( config );
demoAwait();

async function demoAwait() {
    try {
    const results1 = await ac.query( 'SELECT * FROM table' );
    const results2 = await ac.query( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE whatever' );
    console.log(results1); // all above results are available
    // throw 'test error'; uncomment to test an error
    } catch ( err ) {
    console.log(err);
    } finally {
    await ac.close();
    }
}

function awaitableConnection( config ) { // wrapped in a promise
    const connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    return {
      query( sql, args ) {
        return util.promisify( connection.query )
          .call( connection, sql, args );
      },
      close() {
        return util.promisify( connection.end ).call( connection );
      }
    };
}
```

The technique remains readable when queries are placed in a loop. I have to acknowledge Michał Męciński for the pattern of this technique. In Sept 2019 he updated the article fedesc linked above while taking advantage of node.js 8 or later. The article also demonstrates how to use a similar technique for transactions. [Node.js, MySQL and async/await](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628)

Answer (score 1):

1st of all thank you kind responders.

The answer of both of you was indeed the same and the correct one. So i just accepted the quickest responder.

**NPM Mysql functions do operate in an old school callback style (and needs to be updated)** What was really strange for me is that an `INSERT` statement did work out of the box - I guess this is because you don't really need a callback if you don't need data to be retrieved.

And `async/await` is part of node and not mysql.

So the call did indeed fired but without a callback.

```
Connection.prototype.query = function query(sql, values, cb) {
  var query = Connection.createQuery(sql, values, cb);
  query._connection = this;

  if (!(typeof sql === 'object' && 'typeCast' in sql)) {
    query.typeCast = this.config.typeCast;
  }

  if (query.sql) {
    query.sql = this.format(query.sql, query.values);
  }

  if (query._callback) {
    query._callback = wrapCallbackInDomain(this, query._callback);
  }

  this._implyConnect();

  return this._protocol._enqueue(query);
};
```

Therefore your answers are accurate and correct.

**Allow me to elaborate on a possible solution i found for my problem with the hope that maybe it'll help readers who face this approach issue as well.**

There is a workaround i've found when still searching for a solution [here - How to use classes in Node.js (with no pre-compilers), and why you should](https://m.dotdev.co/how-to-use-classes-in-node-js-with-no-pre-compilers-and-why-you-should-ad9ffd63817d) and [here - Node.js, MySQL and promises](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b)

The solution was `"promisifying"` mysql functions with a `class` alike function that converts all `mysql` functions to promises.

Which than will give the option to work with database in an `async/await` approach.

Also there are tools that `promisify` functions that uses callbacks [like this one here](https://codeburst.io/quick-dig-promisify-in-node-js-6d5d763f847d)

```
//mysql
const mysql = require('mysql');
function Database() {
  this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : '*************',
    password : '*************',
    database : '*************',
    multipleStatements: true
  });
  
  this.query = (sql, args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
        if (err)
          return reject(err);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  };

  this.close = () => {
    return async () => {
      try {
        this.connection.end(err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          return;
        });
      } catch(e) {
        return e;
      }
    }
  };
};
var connection = new Database();
```

Setting you db connection this way will allow you now to use `async/await` as in original question.

```
let sortCategory = async (id) => {
    try {
      var sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id=?';
      var results = await connection.query(sql, id);
      // console.log(results);
      return results;
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps anyone.