# How to send multiple query results from backend to frontend in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a simple check-in and check-out system for employees. In the main panel I want to show the number of hours worked per day and in another field the weekly total.

I can now show the hours per day in a table, the problem comes when I have to show the total since I make that query to the database with another query.

**With the following code I perform the query and perform a render in the index view using the EJS templates.:**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const week = DateTime.now().weekNumber;
    conexion.query('SELECT * FROM assistance WHERE week = ?', week, (error, results) => {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }else{
            res.render('index', {results: results});
        }
    })
});
```

**With this code I perform the query of the total hours. but I don't know how to show it in the same index view since it is a separate query from the first one:**

```
conexion.query('SELECT time_format(SUM(TIMEDIFF(a.exit, a.entry)), "%H:%i") AS hours from assistance a WHERE a.week = ?', week, (error, results) => {
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }else{
            return('index', {totalHours: results});
        }
    })
```

**In this way I am trying to receive the information in the index view with EJS:**

```
<div>
   <div>Total hours:<%= totalHours%></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try/catch async-await, then just do both queries.

```js
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  const week = DateTime.now().weekNumber

  try {
    // query 1
    const totalHours = await conexion.query('SELECT time_format(SUM(TIMEDIFF(a.exit, a.entry)), "%H:%i") AS hours from assistance a WHERE a.week = ?', week)

    // query 2
    const results = await conexion.query('SELECT * FROM assistance WHERE week = ?', week)

    res.render('index', {
      totalHours,
      results
    })
  } catch {
    res.render('error-page')
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Lawrence. I have been trying with your answer but it throws me an error: <ref *1> Query {   _events: [Object: null prototype] {     error: [Function (anonymous)],     packet: [Function (anonymous)],     timeout: [Function (anonymous)],     end: [Function (anonymous)]   },... I was researching and found an article that talks about multiple Statements is it the same or another option, you know? thanks for your support.

Comment: what is `conexion`? an instance of what lib?

Comment: conexion is the connection to my MySql database. I create it with the **createConnection** method. then to use it in my queries I invoke the file: **const conexion = require('../database/db')**

Comment: I am using express framework

Comment: so your using mysql package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572105/getting-query-object-instead-of-results-with-async-await-function-and-npm-mysql/62575227#62575227

Comment: yes i am using this mysql package

Comment: thanks lawrence, I checked the link you left me and it worked, I just needed to adjust the connection file to the database so that async/await would work.